# Yet another: git svn not working on OS X Mavericks

Tags: xcode, git, svn

I've seen a lot of complaints about git-svn not working on Mavericks. I haven't seen my case discussed. I recently (involuntarily) upgraded from 10.7 to 10.9. Things worked fine until the upgrade.  Now `git svn clone` fails with this error:

```
W: Filesystem has no item: '/!svn/bc/8534/NavySpear' path not found at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/git-core/perl/Git/SVN.pm line 153.

W: Ignoring error from SVN, path probably does not exist: (160013): Filesystem has no item: '/!svn/bc/100/NavySpear' path not found
```

The svn repository does exits, and I've been careful to avoid typos.

I've got:

- git version 1.8.5.2 (Apple Git-48)
- svn version 1.7.10 (r1485443)
- Xcode 5.1.1

Any ideas?

**Update**

I ended up trying Homebrew.  This worked without any of the tweaks suggested by Google searches.  I guess those tweaks applied to earlier versions.  One thing that I did have to figure out on my own was that by default OS X puts /usr/local/bin behind /usr/bin in the system PATH.  I don't understand the reasoning for that, but there probably is a reason.  At any rate, I had to put /usr/local/bin in front of /usr/bin.  There is more than one way to do that on OS X.  To do it only for yourself, fix it in ~/.bash_profile with

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

or equivalent.

To fix it system-wide edit /etc/paths, and move /usr/local/bin from the bottom of the list to the top of the list.

Either way, after making the edits re-load .bash_profile:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

or open a new terminal session.
For the record, I now have 
git version 2.1.0 
svn version 1.8.10

Answer (score 0):

You need the Xcode command line tools and a link that Apple [seems to have forgotten](http://blog.victorquinn.com/fix-git-svn-in-mountain-lion) to create:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level/SVN /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.16/SVN
```

Alternatively, you'll need to install [SVN](http://search.cpan.org/~mschwern/Alien-SVN-v1.7.17.1/src/subversion/subversion/bindings/swig/perl/native/Core.pm) from CPAN using:

```
perl -MCPAN -e'install Git::SVN'
```

Best of luck and if you have further problems, do leave a comment.

Comment: Thanks!  But still no luck.  Same messages. Things seem to begin ... the terminal flashes "Checked through r100"  ...r200, etc up to at least r8500.    Then it silently stops.  There are no files in the local directory, and .git is full of empty directories.  An svn checkout of the same remote repository succeeds.

Comment: Just checked svn:  r8516 is the last commit.  So the remote repo is being seen and walked, but the files are not appearing.  The structure of the remote is not standard, FWIW.

Comment: Do repeated calls to `git svn fetch` after this happens return the same error?

Comment: with *git svn fetch*, the "Filesystem has no item ..." warning is repeated, along with the "this might take some time" warning, then nothing.  The revision numbers are not printed as they are during the clone phase.

Comment: Actually what I wrote above happens after the *first* call to fetch.  On subsequent calls there's a warning "W: Ignoring error from SVN, path probably does not exist: (160013): Filesystem has no item: '/!svn/bc/8534/NavySpear' path not found".   What is that path with the "!" ??

Comment: Are you behind a proxy, by any chance? If so, comment out `http-proxy-host` to ~/.subversion-servers in the global section and enable it per repository.